# Collaborative Software Platform

Tags: version-control, collaboration, issue-tracking, software-lifecycle

I am looking for what I could describe best as a collaborative software platform for our group (30+). We are currently using just a few svn repositories and it has grown unmanageable.

Our requirements are:

- install-able on our own servers
- revision control (should include svn not to scare the non tech people away)
- issue tracking (bugs, tasks, etc.)
- managing projects (users would be also nice)
- mixed FOSS & closed source projects

From my research I found the following:

**Launchpad (itself)**

- pro: about everything
- con: no svn

**FusionForge**

- pro: similar to SourceForge, has about all features
- con: not sure how actively developed, should be quite cumbersome to manage
  FusionForge

**Gitorious (itself)**

- pro: also about everything on our list
- con: only git, not sure about Ruby's security, intended only for FOSS

My biggest headache is that this platform should scale well also for not technically gifted developers while still keeping a minimum level of code quality.

Experiences with the 3 above or similar would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you really want an all-in-one bug tracker, project manager, and document sharing/discussion system? Be careful what you wish for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple that might fit your needs are:

- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org)
- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org)

They are both has software project management features like:

- Integrated defect tracking
- Integrated wiki
- Forum
- Integration with wide range of version control software, including SVN
- Flexible user authentication, mostly it relies on the web servers's authentication mechanism.

They are both open source and free. Redmine is developed using Ruby on Rails while Trac is using python.

Comment: I would say, Trac is not too good, indeed :) We just migrated from Trac to JIRA and are very happy about it.

Comment: I do prefer Redmine over Trac. I think Redmine started of as clone of Trac, but the development pace and available features have surpass Trac by leaps and bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we will be setting up a test machine running [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and evaluate it in our group :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JIRA from Atlassian. It has a plugin for subversion. You can install it on your own server. It has excellent bug tracking facilities, you can define projects and define roles of users within the projects. You can use it with open and closed source projects. If one of your projects is open source you can apply for a free license.

Comment: Thanx, JIRA looks very promissing.

Comment: I've been using it for a couple of months and I am still very impressed. And I still don't know even half of JIRA's features! Plus there is plenty of amazing add-ons on top of basic functionality. No wonder companies like Facebook, Zynga, Twitter, Adobe, NASA, and so on, and on, use it: http://www.atlassian.com/company/customers?tab=jira As I already mentioned, if just one of your projects is open source you can apply for a free license, which we took advantage of, but I think the pricing is reasonable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build life around SVN as VCS-core, you have to see at [UberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/)

More costly (extremely, compared to zero-price) solution, not limited by only Subversion, is [Private Assembla](http://private.assembla.com/index.html)

Comment: Assembla is a hosted service, so it can't be installed on local server.

Comment: @DJ. **Private** Assembla is [VMware Virtual Appliance](http://private.assembla.com/private-download.html), usable locally

Comment: my fault. I didn't check the _private_ part.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) from Countersoft. It provides all the features you are looking for, either build in, or via free plugin (for SVN integration).